# My Responsive Website looks different in mobile than on a thin browser

Tags: css, responsive

I am currently designing the mobile view for my website. An image on the site is correct in browser responsive view, yet when I view the site on mobile the image is not correct.

I expect the image to look like this:
[image: 1]

Yet it looks like this on mobile:
[image: 2]

The container hides overflow-y and the image is set to width:100%, height:fit-content;

```
        <div id="aboutIntro" class="flex-col">
            <div id="imageContainer">
                <img src="../../images/assets/aboutPic.jpg">
            </div>

            <section id="aboutIntroText" class="flex-col">
                <hr class="small-hr">
                <h2>Web Developer</h2>
                <p><b>Hello. I’m Danny and I am a young professional filled with ambition. I currently attend university where I study software engineering. Outside of education I spend most of my time designing and building digital products.</b></p>
                <hr class="small-hr">
                <p>Last year, I set out focus on becoming a web developer. After attending training courses and dedicating myself I’ve curated all the necessary skills for success.</p>
            </section>
        </div>
```

```
        #imageContainer{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            max-height: 427px;
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        img{
            height: fit-content;
            width: 100%; 
        }
```

Comment: Cannot help you without the code

Comment: Make sure you have width=device width meta tag in your HTML https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: @ZachJensz I do

Comment: @ZachJensz I've added snippets of the code in use, is anymore code needed?

Comment: Have you tried to simply set `img { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }` ?

Comment: Are you using the same browser on your desktop and on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your img `object-fit: contain`

Answer (score 0):

use `object-fit: contain`  or for just the image: `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 0):

img{display:block; height:100%; width:100%}

Object-fit fills the imageContainter, whereas I want to overflow the container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you trying to add more information to your question? You've posted this in the section for _answers_. If you want to edit your _question_ click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72404505/edit) link underneath it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have solved the issue but the answer doesn't align with the question so I'm wanting to delete the question